# Getting SOAP Response time

Tags: c#, winforms

So I have built a CSV Importer that uses web services to send data to and from a system. This is a windows form application.

Now I have various forms in my program and they each take different times to load as part of the application is making SOAP Request on initialization of the form.

I am going to be putting in a progress bar into the application so the user doesn't think that nothing is happening. So what I am wondering is there any way to get the SOAP Response time and have that be my interval for my progess bar?

Comment: Or is there any way to speed up transition times between forms.

Comment: What do you mean, "the SOAP Response time"? Also, are you using "Add Web Reference", or "Add Service Reference", and what version of .NET are you targeting?

Comment: Surely you can only know the response time for a SOAP call *after* the call has already completed, thereby rendering the information useless for a progress bar-type notification. Perhaps you would be better with just displaying "Calling Webservice 1/2/3" on your GUI?